# Passing csv file data into command using .sh file in linux

Tags: linux

I want to pass my n number csv data into command "esusers useradd username -r role -p password". How can i perform this in linux machine. i Have done this window but unable to do in linux machine can anyone help me out of this. My input will contain header also.

Answer (score 1):

**csv file user.csv**:

```
user1,role1,pass1
user2,role2,pass2
user3,role3,pass3
```

**The bash script (scripts.sh) to iterate over the csv file**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check parameters
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
     >&2 echo "Illegal number of parameters"
    exit 1
fi

# Check file
if [ ! -f "${1}" ]; then
     >&2 echo "File ${1} not found"
    exit 1
fi

FILE="${1}"

while read line; do
    USER=`echo ${line} | cut -d"," -f1`
    ROLE=`echo ${line} | cut -d"," -f2`
    PASS=`echo ${line} | cut -d"," -f3`

    echo "adding user ${USER} (role: ${ROLE}) with password: ${PASS}"
    esusers useradd "${USER}" -r "${ROLE}" -p "${PASS}"
done < ${FILE}
```

Then, add execution mode to the script with `chmod +x script.sh` 
and run the script with the csv file as parameter `./script.sh user.csv`

```
$ ./script.sh user.csv
adding user user1 (role: role1) with password: pass1 
adding user user2 (role: role2) with password: pass2 
adding user user3 (role: role3) with password: pass3
```